# Identify this bug (which looks like a cross between a beetle and a bed bug)

Tags: species-identification, entomology

I am located in a large Eastern European city. During this summer, a new kind of bug has started appearing in my house (or more specifically, coming into my house from the garden). It's about 1.5-2 cm long, doesn't appear to have any wings, and a relatively strong exoskeleton (makes an audible crack when the bug is squished). Its favorite activities seem to be either sitting in the middle of the floor, waiting for someone to step on it, or sitting on the ceiling and then falling onto somebody's head. Whenever I see one of them, it's almost completely stationary, regardless of the time of day.

Here are pictures of it (sadly, they're very grainy due to my phone's camera's low quality).

[image: Exhibit 1]

[image: Exhibit 2]

Comment: looks kind of like a stink bug but the color is off and the image is so grainy that I cant quite make out its geometry.  Definitely some kind of beetle though. Did it stink when you stepped on it ?

Comment: I don't recall smelling anything. Most images of stink bugs I found on the internet had a different color on the end of their abdomens, and this is not the case here.

Comment: right, but again I can barely see the bug because the image resolution is so grainy.

Comment: It looks like your camera's smudged.. have you tried wiping it off?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

That is a weevil. Coleoptera, Curculionidae. Weevils have distinctive snouts, and elbowed antennae. They can be crop pests, and eat seeds, but do not spread diseases to humans. I suspect these have just found their way into your home by mistake. https://bugguide.net/node/view/1126677